# Two adjectives for two nouns

Tags: grammar, adjectives

I saw this on a billboard recently

> We have new and pre-owned cars and trucks

Clearly the intention is to modify "cars and trucks" with the two adjectives "used and preowned" and although the construction does make sense intuitively (and colloquially), I was wondering if there are any specific rules about this kind of "dual-and" construction or any other situation where you have multiple adjectives modifying a string of objects simultaneously.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, what do they believe is the difference between *used* and *pre-owned*?

Comment: @Martha: well, I guess theoretically, one can own a car without ever using it. In fact, I don't have a driver's license, so if I win a car in a TV show or something, I'll probably put it on eBay or give it away as *pre-owned* but *not used*.

Comment: @Martha: I agree, it looks like needless wordiness, which is not uncommon in advertising, alas. The theoretical difference is unlikely to have any practical use.

Comment: @Martha: A "Certified Pre-Owned" car (CPO) indicates that the car was inspected by the dealer and passed some long checklist. CPOs usually come with a warranty. A "used" car, on the other hand, is one that has not been inspected and likely carries no warranty other than requirements imposed by the state (such as the ability to return the car within two weeks or purchase, or whatnot). Anywho, I imagine the word "pre-owned" implies **Certified** Pre-Owned, but perhaps there wasn't enough space.

Comment: @Scott: Good info. If only the common phrase "as new" had been used for this, it would have been much clearer.

Comment: @Martha @Scott , its a mistake on my part, Its supposed to be *new*

Comment: @Scott: I would not say that "pre-owned" implies "certified". I think "pre-owned" is used as a euphemism for "used".

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: In this case it might, but @Martha's question was what is the difference between *used* and *pre-owned*. Because sometimes you'll see an ad that says, "We have used and pre-owned cars."

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a "used and pre-owned cars" sort of advertisement, but it seems to me like an advertising psychology/spin issue. 'Used' is like 'used up'; it has someone else's essence (for lack of a better word) all over it. Pre-owned scrubs the thought of the person who owned it (and therefore all the things they may have done in that car) from the front of the mind, therefore making it more appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited]

The problem with this kind of double reference is that it might sometimes give rise to ambiguity. That is why the words "respective" and "respectively" are used when it is necessary to let readers know that the first verb refers only to the first noun, and the second only to the second.

While this example is not really ambiguous, several interpretations are theoretically possible:

> We have used cars, and we have
>   pre-owned trucks.

In this case, you would use "respectively".

> We have used and pre-owned cars, and
>   we have used and pre-owned trucks.

In this case you would not use "respectively". However, since some writers do not use that word where it is needed, the reader is not always sure how to interpret such a sentence if there is no "respectively". It could also be confused with the following interpretation:

> We have used and pre-owned cars, and we
>   have trucks.

My advice is to use this type of sentence only when there is no chance of confusion at all, when there is no chance that the reader would want to read back or speculate as to how it could be intended. Even if some thinking will clear up ambiguity, and even though it is then not explicitly "wrong", why make the reader exert himself if you could also write it such that it is clear immediately?

Comment: @RegDwight: Agreed, this particular example is not really ambiguous. But I understood Crasic to be asking about this construction in general, which can be ambiguous. I will add to my answer that it is not ambiguous in this case.

Comment: I don't really see any basis for assuming the first meaning, absent something in the sentence structure which make it difficult to put each modifier with the thing modified.  "Bob and Joe played USCF-supervised 30-minute games against Larry and Jeff", for example, might be more concise than "Bob played a USCF-certified 30-minute game against Larry, and Joe likewise against Jeff".  In your example, though, "used cars and pre-owned trucks" would actually be a word shorter than "used and pre-owned cars and trucks".  For the latter meaning, "as well as" serves as an "and" which detaches modifiers.