# "Find ten apples and oranges" Do I find 10 or 20?

Tags: grammatical-number, ambiguity

If I read the sentence

> Find ten apples and oranges.

Do I need to find ten or twenty pieces of fruit?

Comment: Yes‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎.

Comment: Ask, on math ;)

Comment: Maths has it sorted. 10(a + o) or 10a +yo or xa + yo where x + y = 10 (or even 10h where h is a hybrid). Using a, o and h as abbreviations rather than unknown numbers, but still subject to the laws of algebra, of course.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What quantity am I saying here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/what-quantity-am-i-saying-here)

Answer (score 8):

I think its ambiguous.  If the question was:

"Find ten apples and ten oranges."  this is no ambiguity.

**It is the writer's responsibility to communicate clearly and without ambiguity.**

If you have to struggle to determine which of three or four possible questions is actually being asked, it's not YOUR fault, it's his.

Comment: So true but the spoken word is often culturally influenced, and our standard does not necessarily parallel

Comment: @ThirdNews You are correct, but we should always strive for clarity.

Comment: Your point is valid but mine is that they believe they are speaking clearly; interpretation is a matter of cultural sensitivity

Comment: @ThirdNews  We are in agreement......................

Comment: I agree it's ambiguous, but I think that if I was forced to pick an interpretation I'd go with 10 pieces of fruit total... Since they *didn't* specify, I default to the least specific understanding. Just my $0.02; +1!

Comment: @WendiKidd  Perhaps you are correct....... I apologize if I am ranting...

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No, not ranting at all! I was agreeing with you :)  Just also adding what I think the default reading would be, for me anyway. I gave you an upvote! :)

Comment: @WendiKidd  Thank you.....your interpretation may be correct, I don't know.......

Comment: [Cerberus](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8110/two-adjectives-for-two-nouns) agrees with you, Gary's Student: "My advice is to use this type of sentence only when there is no chance of confusion at all, when there is no chance that the reader would want to read back or speculate as to how it could be intended. Even if some thinking will clear up ambiguity, and even though it is then not explicitly "wrong", why make the reader exert himself if you could also write it such that it is clear immediately?" [This related thread was about adjectives rather than quantifiers.] And so do I.

Answer (score 3):

**And** can be both a *distributive coordinator* and a *joint coordinator*. So, for example, if a subject includes a distributive **and**, then the predicate applies equally and distinctly to both noun elements:

> John and Mary live in London

means

> John lives in London and Mary lives in London.

A subject including a joint **and** cannot be expanded in this way. So,

> John and Mary are a happy couple

is incoherent as

> John is a happy couple and Mary is a happy couple.

Often, however, there is no way to reliably interpret if the **and** is a *distributive coordinator* or a *joint coordinator*. For example:

> John made cheese and cucumber sandwiches.

Did all the sandwiches consist of both cheese and cucumber (*joint coordination*) or did he make cheese sandwiches and also make cucumber sandwiches (*distributive coordination*)?

The OP's sentence *Find ten apples and oranges* is ambiguous in the same way.

There is a brief discussion of distributive / joint coordination in [The Handbook of English Linguistics](http://books.google.de/books?id=7lbaAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=joint%20distributive%20coordinator&source=bl&ots=jvoyJZNmPM&sig=i8AUqyP4zg0cpEPpOrYs9XbCDLg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vn5bU_rEK8bOsgbYkYG4Aw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=joint%20distributive%20coordinator&f=false) (Aarts).

......................

[edit]

Various examples where this distributive/joint coordination ambiguity occurs are:

- *Six lions and tigers escaped*.                                [Numeral] [Nₚₗ₁] and [Nₚₗ₂]
- *They are wearing blue shirts and shorts*.         [Adj] [Nₚₗ₁] and [Nₚₗ₂]
- *He is wearing a blue shirt and tie*.                       a [Adj] [Nₛ₁] and [Nₛ₂]
- *Jim and Jill are married.*                                     [Nₛ₁] and [Nₛ₂] are married.
- *John married Jo and Evelyn.*                              X married [Nₛ₁] and [Nₛ₂]
- *John wears red and white socks*.                      [Adj] and [Adj₂] [Nₚ]
- I met Jo and the other girls who arrived later.       [N₁] and [N₂ or DetP] [relative clause]

Interpretations:

distributive coordination                                              joint coordination

- *Six lions and and six tigers escaped*.                            *Six big cats escaped*.
- *They are wearing shorts and blue shirts*.             *They are wearing blue shirts and blue shorts.*
- *He is wearing a tie and a blue shirt*.                          *He is wearing a blue shirt and a blue tie.*
- *Jim is married; so is Jill*.                                             *Jim is married to Jill.*
- *John remarried.*†                                                             *John officiated at the wedding.*†
- *John wears [both] red socks and white socks.*             *John wears red-and-white socks.*
- The other girls arrived later than Jo.                             Jo and the other girls arrived later.

† The polysemy of 'marry' (symmetric or factitive) adds a layer of complication.

Comment: For *"John made cheese and cucumber sandwiches"*, there's a third possibility. Compare *"John made tea and cucumber sandwiches"*.

Comment: @PeterShor What's the third possibility? I'm intrigued but I wasn't able to figure it out myself from your comment :)

Comment: @WendiKidd is that John is making cheese (not cheese sandwiches) and also making cucumber sandwiches.

Comment: Ahh, I think I read the answer a bit too quickly. The "cheese sandwiches + cucumber sandwiches" option was actually the one that hadn't occurred to me. It's so interesting how many interpretations there can be of one sentence!

Comment: And you can combine two of the interpretations to get the possibly zeugmatic sentence *"John made cheese and cucumber sandwiches and tea and tomato sandwiches."*

Comment: The Bayer article linked to below goes further, saying that there are at least three different usages of _and_. It further claims that these can relate with modifiers and determiners in different ways.

Comment: One example showing different behaviour is 'bacon and eggs is my favourite meal'. Joint according to the above classification, but so joint as to be afforded singular agreement.

Comment: Could you add a list showing the structure of various ambiguous coordinations, for completeness? [Numeral] [Nₚₗ₁] and [Nₚₗ₂] // [Adj] [Nₚₗ₁] and [Nₚₗ₂] // [Nₛ₁] and [Nₛ₂] are married // [Adj₁] and [Adj₂] [Nₚ]  // ..?.. Or may I edit these in?

Comment: @Edwin. I'm pretty busy at the moment. So please go ahead with your suggestion. That would be a useful addition to my answer on this interesting topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's like someone saying they *"have three brothers and sisters"*.
Is that a total of six siblings or three? Do they have two brothers and one sister, or two sisters and one brother?

As a result we can read the OP's sentence as

1. Find ten apples [and oranges] = 20 pieces of fruit (ten oranges being implied)
2. Find ten [apples and oranges] = 10: any combination of the two types of fruit.

Possible variations which would avoid this ambiguity:

> Find ten of each fruit: apples and oranges. (20)
>   Find ten apples and ten oranges. (20)
>   Find ten apples or ten oranges. (10)
>   Find ten fruit which are apples and oranges. (10)