# Detecting logical disjunction of two adjectives

Tags: conjunctions, logic, disjunction

I've failed to find clear rules for generating logical disjunction of two adjectives in English.

Here's a real-life, though dated, example of historical importance:

> *"Tea shall not be consumed, nor sweet **and** black coffee drank".*

When I ask people the following questions about this sentence, I get two different interpretations:

**Interpretation A** ("and" is treated as logical disjunction):

1. Drinking tea is forbidden.
2. Black sugarless coffee is forbidden.
3. Black sweet coffee is forbidden.
4. Non-black sweet coffee is forbidden.
5. Non-black sugarless coffee is allowed.

**Interpretation B** ("and" is treated as logical conjunction):

1. Drinking tea is forbidden.
2. Black sugarless coffee is allowed.
3. Black sweet coffee is forbidden.
4. Non-black sweet coffee is allowed.
5. Non-black sugarless coffee is allowed.

Which interpretation would you choose?

Comment: Given that different people choose different interpretations, isn't the answer just that the sentence is ambiguous?

Comment: If you say the sentence is from real life, you should tell us where you found it.

Comment: This is why most people would say "sweet black coffee" not "sweet and black coffee". Nonetheless, you may or may not be able to tell from the context, which is why knowing where it's from is important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Find ten apples and oranges" Do I find 10 or 20?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166286/find-ten-apples-and-oranges-do-i-find-10-or-20) '_And_ can be both a distributive coordinator and a joint coordinator.... "John made cheese and cucumber sandwiches. ":  two types, or one more interesting type?' {@Shoe} [sweet-] and [black-] [coffee], distributive, = [sweet coffee] & [black coffee] // [sweet-and-black] [coffee], joint, = [coffee that is sweet and black]. Either reading is available. //// ...

Comment: It's even possible this is just used as a descriptor (crude paraphrase, 'yummy') rather than an identifier: "Tea shall not be consumed, nor coffee ... hmm, how sweet and black ... drank."

Comment: Standard English wants **drunk** there.

Comment: This is why mathematicians avoid expressing their logical statements in English, but instead use boolean algebra notation. This allows expressing the relationships precisely and unambiguously.

Answer (score -2):

The word “nor” is used as a coordinating conjunction to connect two negative elements.

In this case, it connects “Tea shall not be consumed” with “sweet and black coffee drank.” - one type of coffee.

By following the precedence of coordinating conjunctions, The “nor” precedes “and”, so the sentence is connecting two elements tea “nor” coffee, the coffee is both sweet “and” black.

Can coffee be both sweet and black?  Most people called unsweetened coffee “black” coffee. That is a bit ambiguous and would suggest the author should be clearer. We’ll look to rules to sort it out. It’s as clear as mud.

In classical logic, disjunction is true unless both of its disjuncts are false.
Inclusive disjunction allows a formula to be true when both of its disjuncts are true.

Those two possible Interpretations lead one to assume the author was distinguishing between two types of coffee (black and sweet). Otherwise, no need to include non-black and unsweetened combinations in Interpretation A & B.

The logical disjunction here is between “sweet coffee” and “black coffee.”
We can interpret this as follows:
s: “The coffee is sweet.”
b: “The coffee is black.”
The sentence implies that neither sweet coffee nor black coffee should be consumed.

Interpretation A is the correct answer using the classical logic rules where “s” represent sweet coffee and “b” is black coffee:
If the coffee is both sweet and is black (s is true, b is true), the compound statement is true.
If it’s just black (b is true, s is false) or is just sweet (b is false, s is true), the compound statement is still true.
Only when neither condition is met (both s and b are false) does the compound statement become false.

Let’s suppose the author is referring to one particular type of coffee (Sweet and Black).

The logical disjunction here is between “tea” and “sweet and black coffee.”
We can interpret this as follows:
t: “tea”
c: “sweet and black coffee.”
The sentence implies that neither sweet coffee nor black coffee should be consumed.

Interpretation B is the correct answer using the classical logic rules where “t” is tea and “c” is sweet and black coffee:

If tea is consumed (t is true, c is false) or sweet and black coffee is drank (t is false, c is true), the compound statement is still true.

Only when neither condition is met (both t and c are false) does the compound statement become false.

If the question did not ask to choose one of the two given interpretations, I’d assume the sentence is a prohibition on drinking tea and sweetened coffee.

The logical disjunction here is between “tea” and “sweetened coffee.”
We can interpret this as follows:
t: “tea”
c: “sweetened coffee.”

The sentence implies that tea nor sweetened coffee should be consumed.

Interpretation C.

- Tea should not be consumed.
- Black Coffee that has been sweetened should not be drank.
- Black Coffee that has not been sweetened is allowed.
- Non-black coffee that has been sweetened may be allowed. However, you risk misinterpreting the rules of The Ministry of Beverage Consumption and might want to ask for clarification before proceeding, especially if the penalty is severe.

Comment: Basically, the string 'red and blue socks' is ambiguous'; this was spelled out in the previous thread.

Comment: True. What is the rule for handling when a person says they want a car that is a Mercedes and BMW?  They want the color to be Black and White?  Both are ambiguous, but distinguishable using classical logic rules.  BMW and Mercedes cannot be true at same time.  Black and white can both be true at same time.